# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric. Could not find stored procedure ''.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm getting this error when executing my stored procedure (`SP_StoredProcedure`):

[image]
My stored procedure (`SP_StoredProcedure`) gathers some data from **VB.NET** before executing

```
dim TableName string = "Table1"
dim acctcode as string "Table1.acctcode"
dim month as integer = 1
dim year as integer = 2011
```

Here is my code for executing stored procedure (`SP_StoredProcedure`) FROM **VB.NET**:

```
execute("EXECUTE SP_StoredProcedure '"& TableName &"','"& acctcode &"',"& month &","& year &"")
```

Here is my code on `SP_StoredProcedure`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoredProcedure]
@TableName as varchar(100),
@AcctCode as varchar(100),
@Month as numeric(18,0),
@Year as numeric(18,0)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Query as varchar(1000)
SET @Query = 
'UPDATE Table2 SET Dat = (SELECT Dat FROM '+ @TableName +' WHERE table2.acctcode = '+ @acctcode +' AND month = '+ @month +' AND year = '+ @year +') FROM Table2'
EXEC @Query
END
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM FROM` sum of what?

Comment: Declare `year` and `month` as `Double` rather than `int`

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri SUM is just a column name

Comment: If `SUM` is column name, you should put it in `[ ]`, like this: `[SUM]`

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều it's not really my exact column name. I'll just change the sample to avoid confusion. sorry

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl I changed it to double, still no luck. Same error message :-(

Comment: I think you should declare `@month` and `@year` are `int` type

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều Tried it too. Now it is saying `error converting data type to int`

Comment: So, what are Table1.month and Table1.year columns data type?  INT, NUMERIC, other

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều they are both Numeric(18,0)

Comment: change `dim month as integer` to `dim month as decimal`. (year)

Comment: it doesn't seem to affect the result because i still get the same error. :-(

Comment: Also I noticed I got two errors. the other one is `Could not find stored procedure`. based on the image I uploaded on my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing dynamic queries in varchar strings the numeric values need to be converted and this is important for dates too!  Otherwise it doesn't append properly to the @Query variable.

Also if  @acctcode is a varchar, then you need to escape it with extra single quotes so that that it will handle it like a string properly.

ie..

```
SET @Query = ' UPDATE Table2 ' + 
             ' SET Dat = ( ' +
             '     SELECT Dat FROM ' + @TableName + 
             '     WHERE table2.acctcode = '''+ @acctcode +''' +
             '     AND month = ' + convert(varchar(18), @month) + 
             '     AND year = '+ convert(varchar(18), @year) +
             ' ) ' + 
             ' FROM Table2 '
```

Comment: it gives me this error:  `The name ' UPDATE Table2 ' + 
             ' SET Dat = ( ' +
             '     SELECT Dat FROM ' + @TableName + 
             '     WHERE table2.acctcode = '+ @acctcode + 
             '     AND month = ' + convert(varchar(18), @month) + 
             '     AND year = '+ convert(varchar(18), @year) +
             ' ) ' + 
             ' FROM Table2 ' is not a valid identifier.`

Comment: Sorry i was editing it, try now with the extra single quotes around the @acctcode   this needs to be escaped.

Comment: just the @acctcode? how about the @tablename?  may I know why?

Comment: All strings are assigned or tested like..  String = 'TEST'  they are surrounded with single quotes..  Right, Basic SQL.   However, when you are adding the table name,  this is just text you are appending. So you don't need to surround it with single quotes because when you write a normal query,  it's not like ..  select * from 'TABLENAME' right.